# Inner shadow for navigation controller in split view controller

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, gradient, shadow

I'm really struggling to get an inner shadow to work on an app I'm writing as I'm not sure the best way of doing it.

I have a UISplitViewController which contains a UINavigationController as the master view. What I'm after, is a drop shadow over the menu on the left (or an inner shadow inside it) 
Similar to [this app](http://theiphoneguru.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/iphone-guru-ipad5.jpg)

I can't figure out how to get this to work and it's driving me mad. I've looked in the appearance proxy, but you can't use it on either the navigation controller or split view controller (which makes sense)

I've subclassed the navigation controller and tried drawing things in viewDidLoad and am able to add a subview to the controllers view but I can't get a shadow to work. I can't use drawRect as this app is for iOS5 and this has been removed in place of the appearance proxy.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Not to worry. I sorted it a different way.

I created a UIView subclass that draws a simply gradient the width/height that I want, and I then add that as a subview when my navigation controller loads.

Thanks anyway :)